# Gulp work in sequence

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-shell

I ran into a problem where I have a task for a shell script and some other tasks I want to run in order. I've solved this issue for regular tasks by including run-sequence plugin. But the thing with that plugin is that every task should return a stream which is not the case with my task for shell (I cannot return a stream in it). I need to run my 'pack' task after others have been finished so I tried this option

```
gulp.task('pack', ['build'], function () {
    shell.task(config.packHtml.cmdLineString) 
});
```

But my 'pack' task doesn't seem like works correctly. Here's the whole code

```
    var gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
    order = require('gulp-order'),
    replace = require('gulp-replace'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    combiner = require('stream-combiner2'), //NOTE: alternative to merge-stream
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    shell = require('gulp-shell'),
    config = require('./config');

gulp.task('build', function () {
    runSequence('concat', 'replace');
});

gulp.task('concat', function () {
    var combined = combiner.obj([
            gulp.src(config.concat.src),
            order(config.concat.order, {base: './'}),
            concat(config.concat.fileName),
            gulp.dest(config.concat.dest)
        ]);

    combined.on('error', console.error.bind(console));

    return combined;
});

gulp.task('replace', function () {
    var combined = combiner.obj([
            gulp.src([config.replace.dest + '/' + config.replace.fileName]),
            replace(config.replace.regExpForInclude, ''), 
            replace(config.replace.regExpForTarget, ''), //NOTE: make it in 1 regExp
            gulp.dest(config.replace.dest)
        ]);

    combined.on('error', console.error.bind(console));

    return combined;
});

// gulp.task('pack', 
//     shell.task(config.packHtml.cmdLineString) 
// );

gulp.task('pack', ['build'], function () {
    shell.task(config.packHtml.cmdLineString) 
});
```

Any suggestions? I want to run all tasks with one command (of course if I run 'build' first and then 'pack' it'll work perfectly).

Comment: I already fixed that. A little bit later I will add the answer. Thank you anyway!